# WPF ItemsControl can't bind Command

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm a newbie in wpf and i know that this question has been asked other times, and i tried to implement some solutions that i found. But it's not working. I'm doing something wrong but i can't see what it is.
I've created a new simple application to test this problem.

```
namespace WpfApp3
{
    public class MyElement
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public MyElement(string t)
        {
            Text = t;
        }
    }

    public class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _handler(parameter);
        }

        private Action<object> _handler;
        public MyCommand(Action<object> handler) { _handler = handler; }
    }

    public class MyItemsControlViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<MyElement> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<MyElement> MyElementItems { get { return _items; } set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged("MyElementItems"); } }
        ObservableCollection<MyElement> _temporayList;
       
        private ICommand _itemClicked;
        public ICommand ItemClicked { get { return _itemClicked; } }

        public MyItemsControlViewModel()
        {
            _items = new ObservableCollection<MyElement>();
            _temporayList = new ObservableCollection<MyElement>();
            _itemClicked = new MyCommand(OnItemSelected);

            AddItem("Element 1");
            AddItem("Element 2");
            AddItem("Element 3");
            UpdateList();
        }

        public void UpdateList()
        {
            MyElementItems = _temporayList;
        }
        public void AddItem(string t)
        {
            MyElement item = new MyElement(t);
            _temporayList.Add(item);
        }

        public void OnItemSelected(object param)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Executed!");
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.MyUserControl"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
                  mc:Ignorable="d" 
                  d:DesignHeight="1080" d:DesignWidth="570"
                  x:Name="myCustomControl">
    <Grid >
        <Button x:Name="btnOutsideItemsControl"  Width="100" Height="100 " VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding ItemClicked}" />
        <ItemsControl 
            x:Name="listItems"             
            ScrollViewer.PanningMode="None"
            IsEnabled="False"
            Background = "Transparent"         
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyElementItems}" Margin="0,152,0,0" Width="549">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,0,0,0" 
                                        Background="Transparent" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button 
                    Content="{Binding Text}"
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=listItems, Path=DataContext.ItemClicked}"/>

            </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The component is used in MainWindow.xaml.

```
namespace WpfApp3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MyItemsControlViewModel _myViewModel;
        public MyItemsControlViewModel MyViewModel { get { return _myViewModel; } }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            _myViewModel = new MyItemsControlViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();

            myCustomControl.DataContext = MyViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myCustomControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When i run the application i can see correctly the list of 3 items with the correct text.
But if i click on one of the button of the list i can't see the output of Debug.WriteLine("Executed!");

But if i click on the button *btnOutsideItemsControl* that is outside the ItemsControl, it works. I can see the output of Debug.WriteLine("Executed!");
So i think that also the definition of the command is correct.

To bind correctly the Command property of Button inside the ItemsControl i try this

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=listItems, Path=DataContext.ItemClicked}">
```

And also this

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemClicked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
```

But it not works.

Please help!

Comment: This is confusing. The view model has a empty OnItemSelected method that is supposed to be executed by the ItemClicked, but you are talking about a OnMyItemSelected method. Where is that? Try to reduce your code to a minimal reproducible example. Remove things that are unrelated to the problem.

Comment: As a note, `UpdateList()` will not notify the UI, since you set the backing field, but not the property `MyElementItems`.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens for your reply and suggestions. I changed the question. I've created a new application WpfApp3 and add the minimum code needed to see my problem. If it is still confusing, please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna kick yourself once I tell you.

Your problem is that you set `IsEnabled="False"` on your `ItemsControl`.  Remove it and all will be well with the universe.

Comment: Yes I definitely want to kick myself! I don't know how I didn't see it! Thank you very much